# Matching algorithm, match pairs: what would be the right way to do it?

Tags: algorithms, sorting

How would you solve the following problem...
Theres a table filled with data like this:

```
Data1: 50 51 48 55 50
Data2: 51 49 52 50 51
Data3: 49 53 50 51 48
Data4: 48 50 52 51 53
Data5: 47 50 51 54 49
Data6: 50 48 50 49 52
Data7: 51 50 51 49 51
Data8: 48 51 49 50 50
...
```

The goal is to create pairs from the table, based on similarity of the rows.

**As i learned from the comments, it is matching, thx :)**

A difference bigger than 3 is not allowed.

When values are close to each other, they should be paired, for example

```
Data2: 51 49 52 50 51
Data7: 51 50 51 49 51
```

have very close values and should be a paired/grouped. So if this is our first pair, what is the next one?
And how to handle outliers (in the columns)? For example

```
Data1: 50 51 48 55 50
```

has in the fourth column the value 55. With the criteria no bigger difference than 3, the only possible companion is Data5:

```
Data5: 47 50 51 54 49
Data1: 50 51 48 55 50
```

But in cloumn 1 and 3 the delta is 3, so in the mean maybe it isnt such a good choice.

Outlier who couldnt be assigned because of the too big deviation, will not be considered.
The algorithm has not to be efficient.

Maybe you can see that it is just not clear for me, how to check the data  against each other. To match the best fitting rows together.

So to answer the question about the use: each datarow is one measured device. You need two devices for the signal reproduction. For the best reproduction result you need maximum coherence between those two. So perfect would be an ideal match. So the goal is to find the best matching devices in the table.

Comment: If the efficiency of the algorithm is of no concern, just compare all possible pairs.

Comment: It is possible to create pairs and check validity. To sort by (decreasing) correlation, you need to define a measure.

Comment: "But not just based on the average of each row, but rather in dependency of the values to one another."   Is not clear.

Comment: I don't think this is a sort. Since your just pairing  I think the Stable Marriage Problem can be used to solve this.
    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem

Comment: This seems to be [maximum-weight matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#In_general_graphs). ​ Is it the entries or the rows or the columns that might be outliers? ​ (i.e., which of those are what might not be considered?) ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: `Maybe you can see that it is just not clear for me` If you (who else would you expect to?) can't pin down how to define a "distance" (sum off absolute differences/squares are somewhat common), try to describe its use: what is this grouping good for?

Comment: @user3853544 It's not stable marriage; just maximum-weight matching (or maybe just matching). Stable marriage requires preference relations and requires the graph to be bipartite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't sorting: it's matching. The vertices of your graph are the data rows and there's an edge between two vertices if the two rows are compatible for pairing (e.g., have no difference bigger than 3, or whatever criterion you want to use).  You're looking for a maximum matching, i.e., a biggest-possible pairing between compatible rows.

It's unclear in your question but you might instead want to define a weighted graph where the weight of an edge is the amount of compatibility (e.g., rows that are very close have a high weight, rows that aren't so close have a low weight, rows that are incompatible have no edge, as before) and compute a maximum-weight matching.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! Hmm I'm not sure if I'm skilled enough to solve this maximum weighted matching problem, since I'm an beginner in programming for 8 years now ;-). Do you think with my basic knowledge of Java and Matlab it is possible for me? And I think yes, the weighted graph in this case would be `data0: 50 50 50 50 50`

Comment: It's a standard algorithm so you'll probably find it implemented by libraries. You'll also need to set up the weights. But programming advice is off-topic, here: [so] will probably be able to help you.